# android - Creating EditText Field with a button

Tags: android, android-edittext, buttonclick

I want to create some EditText fields with one Buttonclick, which have their own names(eText1, eText2 ...)
For example there is a button +. The user can click on that Button to make a new EditText field.

Comment: Which language and framework are you talking about?

Comment: Do you have the EditTexts predefined, or can the user press the button unlimited to create lots and lots of EditTexts?

Comment: the user should create max 100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have given little context, but this piece of code might bring you a litle further:

```
EditText et1, et2, et3;

public void onCreate() {
    et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
    et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
    et3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et3);
    et1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    et2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    et3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

public void clickHandlingMethod(View v) {
    et1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    et2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    et3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Where you just hide all the `EditTexts`, and when the user presses the `button`, makes them visible.

Edit: Seeing your comment that the user may add up to 100 `EditTexts`, you probably want to make something more dynamic. Try this, which creates and adds one on `Button` click:

```
ScrollView container; // create a scrollView in which you can put all EditTexts
static int totalEditTexts = 0;

public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    container = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
}

public void clicked(View view) {
    totalEditTexts++;
    if (totalEditTexts > 100)
        return;
    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    //if you want to identify the created editTexts, set a tag, like below
    editText.setTag("EditText" + totalEditTexts);
    container.addView(editText);
}
```

Edit2: Full code:

```
public class ScrollStuff extends Activity {
    LinearLayout containerLayout;
    static int totalEditTexts = 0;

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.scroll);
        containerLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mlayout);
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        totalEditTexts++;
        if (totalEditTexts > 100)
            return;
        EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        containerLayout.addView(editText);
        editText.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) editText.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        editText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        //if you want to identify the created editTexts, set a tag, like below
        editText.setTag("EditText" + totalEditTexts);

    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Excuse my poor naming choices and the fact that I used `onBackPressed()` for the click event, I'm in quite a hurry.

Comment: @Edu See my edit. Since users may add up to 100, a dynamic approach is better.

Comment: It is possible to click one time on the button but second time it crashes:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child

Comment: @Edu give the scrollview one single child, a linearlayout. Add the edittexts to the linearlayout instead of the scrollview

Comment: Ok thank you, it works but i can't change the position!
LinearLayout.LayoutParams
lllp=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams)et.getLayoutParams();
lllp.gravity=Gravity.RIGHT;
et.setLayoutParams(lllp);

The app crashes

Comment: @Edu see my addition, it's tested code and it fully works. The crash is probably because you add the `editText` after you try to set `layoutparams`, because you want `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` before it is child of a `LinearLayout`

Comment: Ok it is working now. With one Buttonclick i create two edittexts.
The first is on the Left side: layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
and the other on the right:
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

and when i click next i want that the next textfield is below 
("EditText" + totalEditTexts - 2) but i dont know how to do this or wether it is possible to do this...
with linearLayout it wouldn't work because i want to have the edittexts in one line

Comment: tET = totalEditTexts;
editText.setId(tET);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tET - 2);

now it works!

Comment: @Edu Since your problem seems to be resolved, consider accepting an answer.